# C++ CLI draw a line when opening a window

Tags: c++-cli

I have a C++ CLI project, created a new UI. 
Idea is to open this UI and to draw a line or show a picture.
If I call the paint-method directly after InitializeComponent(); or within the drawWindow_Load-method - no success. If I add a button and call the exact same method, i can see the paint. What am I missing?
The .h file:

```
#pragma once
namespace UserInterface {

    using namespace System;
    using namespace System::ComponentModel;
    using namespace System::Collections;
    using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
    using namespace System::Data;
    using namespace System::Drawing;

    public ref class drawWindow : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
    {
    public:
        drawWindow(void)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            paintIt();
        }

    protected:
        ~drawWindow()
        {
            if (components)
            {
                delete components;
            }
        }

    private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^  button1;
    protected:

    private:
        System::ComponentModel::Container ^components;

#pragma region Windows Form Designer generated code
        void InitializeComponent(void)
        {
            this->button1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
            this->SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // button1
            // 
            this->button1->Location = System::Drawing::Point(-1, -1);
            this->button1->Name = L"button1";
            this->button1->Size = System::Drawing::Size(75, 23);
            this->button1->TabIndex = 1;
            this->button1->Text = L"button1";
            this->button1->UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this->button1->Click += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &drawWindow::button1_Click);
            // 
            // drawWindow
            // 
            this->AutoScaleDimensions = System::Drawing::SizeF(9, 20);
            this->AutoScaleMode = System::Windows::Forms::AutoScaleMode::Font;
            this->ClientSize = System::Drawing::Size(278, 244);
            this->Controls->Add(this->button1);
            this->Name = L"drawWindow";
            this->Text = L"drawWindow";
            this->Load += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &drawWindow::drawWindow_Load);
            this->ResumeLayout(false);

        }
#pragma endregion
    private: System::Void drawWindow_Load(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
        //paintIt();
    }
    public: System::Void paintIt();
    private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e);
    };
}
```

and the cpp file:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "drawWindow.h"

System::Void UserInterface::drawWindow::paintIt()
{
    Graphics ^ pg = CreateGraphics(); 

    Pen ^ red_pen = gcnew Pen(Color::Red);

    pg->DrawLine(red_pen, 30, 30, 350, 350);

    delete pg;
}

System::Void UserInterface::drawWindow::button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
    paintIt();
}
```

Comment: Been a while since I've used C++/CLI but my guess is that calling it while the form is still loading/constructing is paradoxical (i.e. nothing to draw on)

Comment: Never use CreateGraphics() to paint unless you program a game that refreshes the screen at a high rate.  Override the form's OnPaint() method or use its Paint event.  Now the OS tells you when you need to draw.  Which is more than once and, you know, not too early.

Answer (score 0):

The following draws a rectangle on my form by overriding the paint function(it should be easy enough to change the rectangle to a line - i.e use g->DrawLine instead of g->DrawRectangle): -

```
    virtual Void Form1::OnPaint(PaintEventArgs^ pe) override
    {
        Graphics^ g = pe->Graphics;
        g->Clear(Color::AntiqueWhite);

        Pen^ redPen = gcnew Pen(Color::Red, 3.0f);

        // Draw rectangle to screen.
        g->DrawRectangle(redPen, 500, 595, 100, 100);  
    }
```

If other controls are present on the form then these will appear in front of the rectangle.